# How do I get my custom Maven Reporting Plugin to appear under the Project Reports in the generated site?

Tags: maven-2, build, maven, maven-plugin

I have written a new maven reporting plugin and it executes when the site is generated and produces and output html file.

How do i get the Project Reports section of the site to contain a link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could manually re-define the project reports section in a custom site.xml:

```
    <!-- Inherit this menu for sub modules. -->
    <menu name="Module Documentation" inherit="top" >
        <item name="Overview" href="index.html" >
        </item>

        <item name="Information" href="project-info.html" >
            <item name="Dependencies" href="dependencies.html" />
            <item name="Project Plugins" href="plugins.html" />
            <item name="Project Summmary" href="project-summary.html" />
            ...
        </item>

        <item name="Reports" href="project-reports.html" >
            <item name="Checkstyle" href="checkstyle.html" />
            <item name="Your Report" href="your-report.html" />
            ...
        </item>
    </menu>
```

The drawbacks are:

- You have to specify every single report.
- You have to provide project-reports.html as well (e.g. via project-reports.apt) and you will lose the automaticly generated overview page with all reports.
- If some modules do not contain all reports, you have to provide individual site.xml files for them to override the parent site.xml.

See [Configuring the Site Descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html) in the documentation of the site plugin.